# bulk insert skip last row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing a bulk insert that I have to skip the last row. Otherwise , I got an error saying "Bulk Insert: Unexpected end-of-file (EOF) encountered in data file."
If I set ROWTERMINATOR='\r\n', then I got 0 rows imported.

I wonder if there is any code that can help me skip the lastrow of the txt file? (The last row is dynamic.) My company currently doesn't have SSIS installed.

My code for bulk insert is

```
Declare @SQL1 varchar(150), @path varchar(100), 

@pathtable varchar(100), @date datetime

set @date = getdate()


-- set path for files

set @path= 'C:\imp\'

set @pathtable = @path + 'importfile.txt'



delete from IDX

--  set sql

set @SQL1 = "BULK INSERT dbo.table FROM '" + @pathtable 

+ "' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, MAXERRORS = 0)"


-- Bulk insert

exec(@sql1)
```

Comment: you can use a format file , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178129.aspx

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, but does that help me skip the lastrow?

Comment: yes, you can mention the number of fields to be read using the format file.

Comment: I want to include all of the fields (columns) except for the last row. I don't think format file can do that?

Comment: In case you know the number of fields in advance and it is fixed, then format file works other wise need to look at some other way

Comment: By chance, the last row.. Is it the number of records affected from an export? For example: (86,034 Rows Affected).

Comment: Oh Good!! Then it's REALLY EASY to solve... Before exporting the data next time, make sure you add at the very top "SET NOCOUNT ON" which will prevent that last row from being generated.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the last row contains a row count from the export process. If you're able to modify the export process, make sure you use the SQL command:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

If you're using a GUI to export the data there should be a place to modify the T-SQL used or an option to set nocount on.

This will prevent the last row from writing out to your file.

If you cannot modify the export process... You can get crazy and right either a console application to read the data and remove the last line or a CLR that does basically that very task.. Open the file, remove the last line, save the file then call your stored procedure above to bulk insert your data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use single quotes `'` multiple times, You have used double quotes `"` which are treated as identifiers in sql server.

Your query should look like this...

```
Declare @SQL1 varchar(150)
      , @path varchar(100)
      , @pathtable varchar(100)
      , @date datetime

SET @date = getdate();

SET @path= 'C:\imp\'
SET @pathtable = @path + 'importfile.txt'


SET @SQL1 = 'BULK INSERT dbo.table 
             FROM ''' + @pathtable + ''' 
             WITH ( 
                     FIRSTROW  = 2
                   , MAXERRORS = 0
                   )';
```

Now if you print this SQL statement it would look like this...

```
PRINT @SQL1

RESULT:

BULK INSERT dbo.table 
             FROM 'C:\imp\importfile.txt' 
             WITH ( 
                     FIRSTROW  = 2
                   , MAXERRORS = 0
                   )
```

Comment: Thanks for your remind, I originally have SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF too